# How to create xlsx file from XML, with using XSLT in java

Tags: java, xml, excel, xslt, xlsx

I am able to create just xls file with an old format, which is Microsoft Spreadsheet 97-2003, but I would rather go for something newer.

How to create newer xlsx format?

I use `javax.xml.transform` java package.

Here is a chunk of java code

```
tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("file.xslt"));
transformer.transform(streamSource, new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(filenameXls)));
```

I have tried using different xsl stylesheet definition, but it didn't help.

This is my xlst file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 Strict//EN" version="1.0"
              doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" xml:lang="pl" />
  <xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <Worksheet ss:Protected="0" ss:Name="Name">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                <style>
                    td {
                        margin:auto;
                        text-align:center;
                        vertical-align:middle;
                    }
                    table th h2 {
                        background-color:rgb(198,239,206);
                    }
                    th.important {
                        background-color:rgb(255,235,166);
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                <tr><th>
                <h2>Articles</h2>
                </th></tr>
                </table>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Lp.</th>
                        <th class="important">Title</th>
                        <th class="important">Date</th>
                        <th class="important">Autors</th>
                        <th class="important">Afilliated</th>
                        <th class="important">Employed</th>

                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="works/article">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="lp"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="publication-date"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="./author">
                                        <li>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="given-names"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="family-name"/>
                                        </li>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="./author">
                                        <li>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="affiliated-to-unit"/>
                                        </li>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="./author">
                                        <li>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="employed-in-unit"/>
                                        </li>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </Worksheet>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why not simply using [**Apache POI**](https://poi.apache.org/)?

Comment: An .xslx file is actually a zip file containing a number of different XML files in various folders. Whilst in theory you could create the XML files using XSLT, it is almost certainly better to use a third-party tool to do it, as mentioned in the previous comment.